# Term for movies taking place during the main events of its predecessor?

Tags: terminology

If a movie follows up after the events of its previous movie, it is called sequel. If it follows up before the events of its predecessor, it is called prequel.

However, what do you call a movie taking place during the events of its previous movie? And what do you call a movie mix up of these kinds? Is there particular terms for them?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

**What do you call a movie taking place during the events of its previous movie?**

It's **Sidequel**, as per [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sequel#Chronologies):

> A sidequel is a story which portrays events that occur at the same
>   time as the original work, but focuses on different characters in a
>   different setting. Such stories may intersect with the original work,
>   and often involve similar themes. One example is the video game Enter
>   the Matrix, which allows players to play out events that occurred in
>   parallel to those in the film The Matrix Reloaded. Another example
>   would be the George R. R. Martin novel A Storm of Swords, which was
>   published in two volumes, each volume describing events which take
>   place at the same time.

**And what do you call a movie mix up of these kinds?**

It's called **Macroquel**

> A macroquel is a companion work that serves as prequel, interquel and
>   sequel to a previous work and covers events before, during, and after
>   the previous continuity. A notable example of this is 300: Rise of an
>   Empire.[*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sequel#Chronologies)

There is one more related term to it called : **Paraquel**

> In a paraquel (parallel story), as with a prequel, the focus is not
>   only on the outcome but on the characters and previously unrevealed
>   information.[6] The Gregory Maguire series (and later Broadway
>   musical) 'Wicked starts as a prequel and develops into a sidequel to
>   L. Frank Baum's book The Wonderful Wizard of Oz and its sequels.[*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sequel#Chronologies)

**Note**: Refer same Wikipedia  link for other similar terms for *quels like Midquel, Interquel, and Pseudosequels.

Comment: And an "interquel" (mentioned in Ankit Sharma's answer regarding a macroquel) is "An installment in a series of works set chronologically between two of its predecessors."

Comment: @BrettFromLA Not asked in teh question itself so I just named droped the rest of *quels

Comment: Right! I just got curious when I saw the word, so I Googled it and added the comment. BTW I thought that you finally uploaded a picture of yourself, but Google tells me that's Joseph Morgan! Oh well. :)

Comment: @BrettFromLA I have added my real picture a lot here but I don't keep any of them for long [here is a list](http://meta.scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/7681/the-many-avatars-of-sff-se/9249#9249), maybe you can track me there ;)

Comment: Seems the only concept that hasn't got a separate "-quel" name is a movie that is in absolutely no way related to the other movie. Maybe we can fix the omission by calling them "unquel" ;-)

Comment: @celtschk they are called Pseudosequels, it's mentioned in the link

Comment: @AnkitSharma: No, those have still a similar title.

Comment: Then I might missed ur point